# 'mongod' not running despite creating the /data/db file

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

I created a /data/db file and this used to work, I'm not sure what changed but when I tried creating a new Schema and testing it with `mongod` I got the following error:

```
2017-12-26T11:08:35.428-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=41342 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Carloss-MBP.home
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.10
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-12-26T11:08:35.429-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

The mongo server runs fine with the command `mongo`, do I have to manually create a `/data/db/mongod.lock` file as well? Not sure what's happening here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already have a mongod process running. Check using 'ps' command and kill if necessary. It is likely that it is holding lock to your /data/db directory.This command should work for you

> mongod --shutdown